# How to fix user pool ******** does not exist in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm new to [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) and [boto 3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) Python SDK. I configured the `Access Key ID`, `Secret Access Key` and the `region name` through [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration).

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

response = client.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId='us-east-2_hJpikme9T',
    Username='wasdkiller'
)
```

Here is my [user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) details,

[image: connection pool details]

I provided the correct `UserPoolId`, but when I run above code sample I got below error for every functions in [CognitoIdentityProvider](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#id108), for an example I used [admin_get_user(**kwargs)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_get_user).

```sh
ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the AdminGetUser operation: User pool us-east-2_hJpikme9T does not exist.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can provide more arguments in [boto3.client(*args, **kwargs)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.client) other than the `service_name`(the default parameter). As you can see [client()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client) in [Session Reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#module-boto3.session), we can provide `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key`, and `region_name` without using [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration).

If you are using default parameters such as you already given through [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration) that's fine, you don't need to mention `aws_access_key_id` or `aws_secret_access_key` when calling [boto3.client()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.client). But I don't know for some reason you have to mention your `region_name` which is you already given through [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration) when calling [boto3.client()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.client).

```py
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-2')
```

In this way I clear out my above problem. But still I don't know why we have to specially mention the `region_name`  argument when calling [boto3.client()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.client), please update this answer or comment below if you know anything about it.

Comment: You needed to manually specify the region because by default, Boto3 takes the region mentioned in the ~./aws/credentials file. In your case, it would be something other than us-east-2.

Comment: oh now I got it thanks to you @ArkaMukherjee, in my `~/.aws/credentials` file there is no `region` variable. But I can see it's in the `~/.aws/config`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Another option is to create the User Pool in region us-east-1. I did that and cognito identity was authenticated successfully.