# Do I need to pass AWS AccessKey and AccessSecret while running AWS batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, boto3, aws-batch

I am using boto3 to communicate with KMS inside a AWS batch job. My code to get the KMS client looks like this:

```py
KMS = boto3.client('kms')
```

My question is, do I need to explicitly pass AWS SecretKey and AWS AccessKey like this:

```py
KMS = boto3.client('kms', 
                   aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                   aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
```

Or

Maybe I just setup environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` while defining a compute environment?

Which is the best option?

Answer (score 6):

When you [Create a Job Definition in AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition.html), you can specify a **Job Role**:

> You can specify an IAM role that provides the container in your job with permissions to use the AWS APIs. This feature uses Amazon ECS IAM roles for task functionality.

Therefore, any code that you write will be provided with credentials based on the Job Role. Your code does not need to specify credentials (so use your first example).

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) for AWS APIs. Because you don't need to worry about managing AWS credentials. Use [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) to manage AWS resources internally, and use [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html) to manage AWS resources externally. So here I'm not going to compare the differences furthermore, I'll attach a few links for your reference.

No need to specify AWS credentials with boto3 whether you use [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) or [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html). Here are the workarounds for [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) and [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html).

You can find the below configurations under the **Job configuration** section.

### [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

Let's assume you have an [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) that has permission for relevant AWS resources. Just select it from the drop-down menu.

[image]

### [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html)

Let's assume you have an [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html) account that has permission for relevant AWS resources. Just enter credential details where you get them when you create an [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html) account to set them as environment variables. In this way, you don't need to hardcode the AWS credentials.

[image]

---

You can choose either [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) or [IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html) based on your requirement. But whatever the thing you choose, you don't need to specifically mention the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`. Sometimes you have to mention `region_name`, this is affected both ways. Because I faced this kind of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56574793/6194097) a few years back.

Anyway if you didn't specifically mention the credentials when you create the boto3 client object, the default value `None` will be assigned. If the `None` is assigned it will check the environment variables, otherwise, will give an error. That's why mentioned, **"you don't need to specifically mention the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`"**.

```py
KMS = boto3.client('kms')  # better if you can mention "region_name" here
```

Hope everything is clear, let me know if you are faced with any difficulties.

References:-

- [Difference between IAM role and IAM user in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46199680/6194097)
- [AWS IAM Users Versus. IAM Roles: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/iam-users-vs-iam-roles-which-one-should-you-use/)
- [When should you use AWS IAM roles vs. users?](https://www.techtarget.com/searchaws/answer/When-to-use-AWS-IAM-roles-vs-users-or-groups)
- [IAM Identities (users, user groups, and roles)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html)